# Flutter Web horizontal scroll with responsive webapp

Tags: flutter

I want to figure out the position of scroll and depending on that results, I want to show some buttons.

This is my code of Scroll Widget.

```
Flexible(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: 730,
        ),
        child: ListView.separated(
            controller: _platformController,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              String platform = platformlistA[index].toLowerCase();
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  if (platformIndex !=
                      platformlistA.indexWhere(
                          (element) => element == platformlistA[index])) {
                    setState(() {
                      platformIndex = platformlistA.indexWhere(
                          (element) => element == platformlistA[index]);
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      platformIndex = -1;
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 37,
                  width: platform != 'fortnite' ? 100 : 85,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 5,
                  ),
                  child: WebsafeSvg.asset(
                    'assets/$platform.svg',
                    color: platformIndex ==
                            platformlistA.indexWhere(
                                (element) => element == platformlistA[index])
                        ? Colors.black
                        : Color(0xffb7b7b7),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(width: 7);
            },
            itemCount: platformlistA.length),
      ),
    ),
```

and this is the code getting the position of Scroll widget.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      setState(() {
        if (_platformController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0) {
          if (_platformController.position.atEdge) {
            if (_platformController.position.pixels == 0) {
              print('left edge');
              // show -> button at right
            } else {
              print('right edge');
              // show <- button at left
            }
          } else {
            print('middle of the scroll');
            // show <-, -> buttons at both side
          }
        } else {
          print('not scrollable');
          // do not show any button.
        }
      });
    });
```

I used `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback` because, it shows error if I handle with controller before the build.

Eventually, this works functionally, but it is too slow since `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback` in `build` function continues to run. I cannot put it in `initstate` because `if()` phrase has to be called everytime when the size of web application changes.

Is there any faster way than this method??? Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'email': email,
  };
```

Try adding => front of toJson()